# How to seperate docker-swarm (containerized infrastructure) into testing and production environment?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

(Not sure whether it is relevant to ask these question here)

I'm wondering `how to` and `what is` best practice to set up and separate testing and production environment in a containerized infrastructure?
(More specifically in a docker-swarm environment. Should it be separated in services?)

And what about the possibilities to connect these environments to each branch (testing and production) in a VCS (e.g GitHub) to this environment, is it doable?